# How to clone IO from one terminal to an other

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am connected directly (tty1) and through ssh (pts/0) to my linux box.

```
who
pi       tty1         2013-09-23 11:33
pi       pts/0        2013-09-23 12:17 (192.168.1.26)
```

I'd like to redirect all input (stdin) and all output (stdout/stderr) from one terminal to another because I'm working with ssh but the audience should be able to follow the session on the big screen (tty1).

The best solution would be if everything (the whole terminal) is copied from one terminal to another.

Any suggestions?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `script` for this:

```
 script makes a typescript of everything printed on your
 terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hard‐
 copy record of an interactive session as proof of an
 assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
 later with lpr(1).
```

You just need to give your `tty` as the output file to `script`:

```
script -f /dev/tty1
```